# MATLAB PID Filter Coefficient

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a problem in producing the algorithm of a PID with Filter Coefficient. The block diagram of the PID with Filter Coefficient looks like this.
[image]

I found an algorithm/code in this link. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63762-filter-coefficient-n-in-pid-block

[image]

Question: Why is that the FilterCoefficient has an unknown variable Filter_DSTATE which has an unknown variable of FilterCoefficient?
The code of FilterCoefficient has an unknown variable of Filter_DSTATE and the code of Filter_DSTATE has an unknown variable of FilterCoefficient?

Hypothesis. Is it one of them supposed to be initialize by some value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open a blank simulink model and add `PID controller` you will get a dialog after double-click

[image]

The derivative term of the PID controller is **never** implemented as a pure derivative because that would be extremely sensitive to noise. Hence, a cutoff frequency is added.

So, the D term will act like *almost* a derivative up to a frequency via

```
          Ns
s ---> --------
        s + N
```

N being the filter coefficient you mention. This also makes it possible to implement a D term using an integrator avoiding a noisy derivative operation.

[image]

Comment: i need an answer as to why is the code like that? its as if the algorithm is like this:

x = y; then,
y = x;

which is impossible to implement via software.

Comment: @PaulJabines It's inside a simulation loop. And the last two have `+=` which is not matlab notation but the original author had some other language in mind C or python. So it's not equality but addition. This is to simulate the integrator behavior. So you can initialize with any valur

Comment: ah ok. so the FILTER_DSTATE is initialized with a value. mostly its 0, right?

Comment: @PaulJabines If you don't specify yes it's zero.